# Cannot find symbol variable google_btn

Tags: android

I want to add google authentication, I am new to android studio and I have the error "Cannot find symbol variable google_btn". Here is my code.

```
    findViewById(R.id.google_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sign_in_with_gmail();
        }
    });
```

Here is a screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsN4H.png

Comment: you should have button in `xml` file with `android:id="@+id/google_btn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an issue with not finding the link in the xml. Which can be down to a few factors. The first is you have not declared the id in the xml. Second you are referencing the xml content when you view it.

You need to firstly identify where you are accessing your `google_btn` from.

If it is inside your `activity_main.xml` check it is created with:

```xml
android:id="@+id/google_btn"
```

```java
//After setting content view
findViewById(R.id.google_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sign_in_with_gmail();
        }
    });
```

Then in your java code for the activity you need to reference that layout to link it.

So in your java code set the view:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);`

This activity should also be inside of your manifest.

After you have gotten the content view you can get the reference to the button

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that you have this button in your layout file (probably res->layout->activity_main.xml). If you have it set its id to google_bnt. Finally, the piece of your code, that sets the `OnClickListener` should be in `onCreate()` method in your activity class (probably `MainActivity.java` in your case)

Comment: I don't have activity_main.xml, I have activity_mainmenu.xml, I also have menu.xml in my menu folder.

Comment: @MazenLovesCoding do you have your button defined anywhere is any xml file?

Comment: Oh, I fixed the problem already by the other comment.

Comment: Mark it as accepted then https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer